# C++ project dependencies failing to compile on a particular macOS box

Tags: c++, xcode, build, cmake, conan

We have a cross-platform C++ project that uses CMake for the build system and Conan for dependency management.

When building on a particular macOS machine, the build fails ([build log](https://gist.github.com/sssilver/f7955ade92557da76158824df70eba83)). It does *not* fail on a different macOS machine running the same version of operating system, CMake, Xcode, and Conan (Conan version: 1.12.3 on macOS 10.14.3 (18D109) and CMake 3.14.0-rc2). Here's [an example of the successful build](https://gist.github.com/sssilver/0e488e8c9764825b9dc4137543675ffb).

Both build logs have been generated by builds with a nonexistent ~/.conan directory on the build machine.

Note that the build *only* fails for the iOS target. The macOS target on the same box builds fine and without any issues.

I have tried, to no effect:

- Nuking ~/.conan
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode

Here's the project's conanfile.py:

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake
from conans.tools import os_info


class SphereGameConan(ConanFile):
    generators = "cmake"
    settings = "arch", "build_type", "compiler", "os"
    requires = (
        "gtest/1.8.1@bincrafters/stable",
        "spdlog/1.3.0@bincrafters/stable",
    )

    def requirements(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows" or self.settings.os == "Macos":
            self.requires("glfw/3.2.1@bincrafters/stable")
```

What may I be missing?

Comment: I don't know anything about Conan but it's using the wrong platform when building `fmt` (`clang: warning: using sysroot for 'MacOSX' but targeting 'iPhone' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]`).  When I've built iOS libraries in the past I've always used stuff like `$(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find clang)` to locate the correct cross-compiler; do you know if cmake/conan does this?  Well asked question BTW +1

Answer (score 0):

We have managed to solve this through something peculiar.

On the box that failed building, we changed `darwin-toolchain/1.0@theodelrieu/stable` in ios.profile to `darwin-toolchain/1.0.4@theodelrieu/stable` (which is the latest version built recently). Somehow, once we did that, the box started building everything correctly. This is the toolchain we use with Conan to be able to compile for iOS.

The million dollar question is -- why was the other box building the project fine while using a version of darwin-toolchain released last August? Probably a bug in Conan.